# Handsfree profile sniff mode

Tags: bluetooth, battery-life

I recently connected a bluetooth module ([BTM511](http://www.sectron.eu/products/147-laird-technologies/150-bluetooth-modules/1355-bluetooth-audio-modules-btm510.html)) to my Android phone (SG2 running android 4.0), using both the handsfree and the headset profiles.

I notice that the Bluetooth device never goes into Sniff mode to save power. As far as I understand only the master (the SG2 in this case) can put the slave into sniff mode. Is this not implemented in the handsfree and headset profile implementation on Android? Or do I not understand the master/slave role in sniff modes? I sure cannot force the BTM511 in sniff mode, it is nowhere to be found in the datasheet.